# MySQL data records need to show in Joomla page

Tags: joomla

I am new to Joomla . So far I have accomplished the following :

i need to add own custom PHP code file and fetch data using MySQL and display in Joomla web page article

Should i do with PHP and MySQL is there any recommended plugin available

Thanks

Comment: Best you read the guide on the [joomla website](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jockham Reports](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/data-reports/sql-reports/) will do that.

If you want more flexibility, you could also use a plugin like [Sourcerer](https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/sourcerer?extension=sourcerer) to put PHP directly into the article, then use JDatabase.  Here is a good tutorial on it: [JDatabase, Using the Joomla Database](http://www.joellipman.com/articles/web-development/joomla/joomla-core/jdatabase-using-the-joomla-database.html)

Comment: Sourcerer is helpful for putting php code into the article @jockham Reports thanks !

Comment: If that worked for you, would you mind accepting my answer?  Thanks!